# How to copy a VM in virt-manager/QEMU while preserving VM state and running applications

Tags: kvm, virt-manager

I'm using `virtual machine manager` on Ubuntu. I want to make a copy of a VM and run it on the same machine while preserving all running applications.

Whenever I save the machine state and try to clone a VM in the GUI, the new VM is shutdown. I have tried making snapshots cloning but the new VM does not have any of the first VM's snapshots.

Is there any way I can pause a VM, copy it, and run a new VM with all the same applications running?

I found this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628454/how-can-i-migrate-backup-restore-a-virt-manager-snapshot) but cannot transfer a snapshot to a VM clone as described because the data in the snapshot XML, such as the UUID, is different in the clone.

Even after changing the snapshot data to match, I get the error:

```
Error running snapshot 'snapshot1':
internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-[uuid of the clone]'
```

Also I have noticed that you can't transfer any snapshots after the first one because they appear to depend on previous snapshots.